# Conditional Probability Exercise - Car Bomb

Tags: probability

I've been trying to work out this exercise on conditional probability, and it has me completely stumped. The question is as follows:

> Consider a garage containing $n$ cars. Exactly one of the cars contains a bomb. The odds of car $i$ containing the bomb equal $p_{i}$. A bomb-sniffing dog goes through the cars. On the condition that car $i$ contains the bomb, then the dog will find it with a probability of $\alpha_{i}$. What are the odds that car $j$ contains the bomb, in the event that the dog did not find a bomb in car $i$?

I've defined my two random variables as

- $ B = $ the car bomb, with set $S_{B} = \{1, ..., n\}$
- $ H_{i} = $ the dog's check on car $i$, with set $S_{H_{i}} = \{True, False\}$

So this leaves me with the following information

- $\mathbb{P}(B = i) = p_{i}$
- $\mathbb{P}(H_{i} = True|B = i) = \alpha_{i}$

And what I'm left to figure out is $\mathbb{P}(B = j|H_{i} = False).$ Supposedly, the answer should be $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha_{j}p_{j}}{\alpha_{i}}$, but I have no idea how to find it. I've tried applying various probability identities without any success. Perhaps I've misinterpreted the information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that the dog *only* checks car $i$ and fails to find it? If so how can the answer possibly depend on $\alpha_j$?

Comment: I translated the exercise more or less word for word. I wasn't quite sure myself if car $i$ is the only one checked given how the exercise is phrased. I imagine it's safe to assume it is though, since the other option would be considerably more complex?

Comment: The supposed answer, $\alpha_jp_j/\alpha_i$, makes no sense: In addition to almagest's observation, if $\alpha_i$ is sufficiently small, then  $\alpha_jp_j/\alpha_i$ can be greater than $1$, hence not a probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question as saying that the only information we have is that the dog has checked car $i$ and failed to find the bomb. We know nothing about any other checks the dog has done.

Suppose the bomb was in car $i$. The prob the dog failed to find it was $1-\alpha_i$, whereas if the bomb was not in car $i$, the prob the dog failed to find it was 1. So given that the dog failed to find it, the prob that it was not in car $i$ is $$\frac{1-p_i}{1-p_i+(1-\alpha_i)p_i}=\frac{1-p_i}{1-\alpha_i p_i}$$

If the bomb is in car $i$ then the chance it is in car $j$ is 0. If the bomb is not in car $i$ then the chance it is in car $j$ is $\frac{p_j}{1-p_i}$ (because the relative probs for the cars other than $i$ is unchanged). So given that the dog failed to find the bomb in car $i$, the prob that it is in car $j$ is $$\frac{1-p_i}{1-\alpha_ip_i}\frac{p_j}{1-p_i}=\frac{p_j}{1-\alpha_ip_i}$$

This disagrees with your statement that the answer should be $$\frac{\alpha_jp_j}{\alpha_i}$$ But that must be wrong. Because if the dog has not checked car $j$ (or we do not know the results of the check) then how can $\alpha_j$ be relevant?

-------- Added later --------

The OP asked for further explanation of the first formula. This is standard conditional probability. Let $B$ denote the event that the bomb was in car $i$ and $B'$ the event that it was not. Let $D$ denote the event that the dog failed to find it. We use $p(D|B)$ to denote the prob of $D$ given $B$.

So $p(D|B)=1-\alpha_i$. Similarly $p(D|B')=1$. We also have $p(B)=p_i,p(B')=1-p_i$. Now the standard Bayesian equation is $p(B'|D)p(D)=p(B'\cap D)=p(D|B')p(B')$, so $$p(B'|D)=\frac{p(D|B')p(B')}{p(D)}$$ But $p(D)=p(D|B)p(B)+p(D|B')p(B')$, so as is often the case it is more convenient to write this equation as: $$p(B'|D)=\frac{p(D|B')p(B')}{p(D|B)p(B)+p(D|B')p(B')}$$ which is the first equation above.

--------- Added later still --------

To amplify the second formula. We have $$p(\text{in car }j)=p(\text{in car }j\ |\text{ in car }i)p(\text{in car }i)+p(\text{in car }j\ |\text{ not in car }i)p(\text{not in car }i)$$ But $p(\text{in car }j\ |\text{ in car }i)=0$. So we have $$p(\text{in car }j)=p(\text{in car }j\ |\text{ not in car }i)p(\text{not in car }i)$$ which is the second formula (although the terms are in the other order).

Comment: I agree the irrelevance of $\alpha_{j}$ makes sense. I'm not quite following your method though. Where does your first formula come from? Also, in the second formula, can you really just chain conditional probabilities like that? I found a little information on a chain rule, but it seems to be applied differently than what you're doing here.

Comment: @Zeno I have added more explanation above on the first equation. The second equation is just saying the prob of X and Y is the prob of X given Y times the prob of Y, which you must have met before.

Comment: More accurately, what you're saying is that $P(A|C) = P(A|B)P(B|C)$. Sort of like a transitive property. If this is correct, why can't I find anything about it anywhere?

Comment: @Zeno I have added further explanation of the 2nd equation.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the 2nd equation separately though. I was talking about multiplying the first with the second. I.e. $P(B$ in $j | H_{i} = False) = P(B$ in $j | B$ not in $i)P(B$ not in $i | H_{i} = False)$.

Comment: $p(\text{in }j)=p(\text{in }j\text{ and in }i)+p(\text{in }j\text{ and not }i)=p(\text{in }j\text{ and not }i)=p(\text{in }j\ |\text{ not in }i)p(\text{not in }i)$ because it cannot be in both.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that doesn't seem to be an answer to my question. My problem regards to the identity in my previous comment, which you're using in your solution, and of which I'm not convinced.

Comment: But I am not using it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but yes you are, it's exactly what you're doing. Your first equation calculates the odds that the bomb is not in $i$ given that the dog didn't find it in $i$, so $P(B$ not in $i|H_{i} = false)$. Your second equation calculates the odds that the bomb is in $j$ given that it is not in $i$, so $P(B$ in $j|B$ not in $i)$. Then you simply multiply these two results. Which is precisely what I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that the bomb cannot be in both cars. The prob the bomb is in j is the prob it is in j and not i plus the prob it is in j and in i. But the last term is zero. So the prob the bomb is in j is the same as the prob it is in j and not in i. The prob it is in j and not in i is the prob it is in j given it is not in i times the prob it is not in i.